# javascript execute function in background

Tags: javascript, multithreading, alert

I searched a lot but I did not found an appropriate answer. What I actually want is execute a method which does a lot of matrix computing it takes ca. 5sec. While this method is executed I want to display a simple please wait alert or something like this.

Is this possible with (native) javascript or not cause js is single-threaded?

Comment: Can you just show the popup before operation and remove it in the end?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: Do you mean in a browser?

Comment: If you have long-running _synchronous computation_, you should use Web Workers.

Comment: @MohammadAdil `setTimeout` does not run things in parallel. It merely allows you to queue up some work for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).
Example:

```
//main.js
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
myWorker.onmessage = function(e) { // function is called when calc is done
  result = e.data;
  // use result
  hideAlert();
}
myWorker.postMessage(calculationParams); // start calculation
showAlert();


//worker.js
onmessage = function(caluclationParams) { // calculation function
  // calculate
  postMessage(result);
}
```